# htaccess Google Seach Console Redirect Error Problem

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

My Wordpress website keeps getting refused by google search console, and i've spent a week trying to fix this problem (tried many different solutions). When I used a third party SEO crawler. It located the redirect error to a problem in [http://www.examplesite.com](https://www.examplesite.com) to http**s**://www.examplesite.com .

Google: Page fetch error Failed: Redirect error

So, having had experience before with SSL and redirects with htaccess with different websites before, i thought this would be an easy fix. apparently it isn't, and I still can't find a fix. I tried many different htaccess solutions. All my links in the xml sitemap use https. all my wordpress settings are set to http**s**://www.examplesite.com . And I have no idea what I am doing wrong, what change, and what to do. I can only think the problem lies in the htaccess file. And I don't what code to use anymore. (yes, i've also disabled all the plugins)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Add code in functions.php:

```php
remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
```